# Debuggers not working in Chrome And FireFox AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs

I am working on hybrid application using AngularJS and Angular 8. I am trying to debug my application for testing purpose but the problem is that debuggers are working fine on **localhost** but it is not working in **staging environment/production environment**. I searched internet for the answers but couldn't find satisfactory solution.

**Below are the screenshots**

**Debugger working on localhost**

[image: Debugger working on localhost]

**Debugger not working on stage environment**

[image: Debugger not working on stage environment]

**Any idea how to fix debugging problem ?**

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug, instead an expected behaviour. When we build the application with '--prod' flag(`ngDevMode=false`) debugger statements are removed away.

Incase you still want it there, you need to disable the '--production' flag and prepare the build. Pleas keep in mind that is will expose your code same as you see in localhost and hence not recommended.

Comment: nd10: but earlier it was working fine like few weeks ago

Comment: Then check if your production build configuration was updated recently. You can find it in angualr.json --> build.

Comment: nd10: my application is running using docker container there is no angular.json file